# How can I retreive all the fields from a firebase document to a map or Key: Value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

need help with retrieving all the fields in a Firestore document. 
I have a react app that gets documents from Firestore.

I am using react-redux-firebase for this. Below is part of my code on the individual component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log(state);
    const collectionName = state.firestore.data.collectionName;

    return {
        data: data
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'collectionName' }
    ])
)(ComponentName);
```

To get a specific field in the document, I do

```
data.fieldName
```

This works well if you know all the field names. My problem is, the fields are not the same for all documents.
It would therefore help if I could get all the fields of each document and return a map or any other key:value pair that i can display to a list on the page. 
In Dart, I could do something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data() => dartify(jsObject.data());
```

I dont know how to do it in React. I am new to the library so any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: So you're asking, given a single JavaScript object returned by data(), what are the properties of that object?  The object returned by data() is not special in any way - it is just a plain JS object an can be worked with as such.

Comment: Yes, and how can I get all the properties in a Key: value format

Comment: The object itself **is** in that format.  All of the document field names are the properties (aka "keys") of the object, and the values are the field values.  You might want to read up on how JavaScript objects work in order to manipulate those keys and values.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: If you have a more specific task at hand than just working with the object (which is very standard JavaScript), please edit the question to state what your goal is and what you've tried so far that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: The task is to render all the Key: Value pairs to a list and display it on a page. I tried  const listThings = user.map((things) => <li>things</li>)      but I get an error, map is not a function. I am sure it's something doable but I am new to js and React isn't making it easy either

Comment: map works for arrays, you can try `Object.keys(things).foreach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to iterate/map over the key/value pairs in an object, you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), among many other options available in [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```
const formatted = Object.entries(data).map(pair => {
    // do something with key and value here
    const key = pair[0]
    const value = pair[1]
    return `${key}: ${value}`
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me and I have managed to get the key: value pairs for all the fields. 
I however get a warning "each child in a list should have a unique key prop" any ideas on how to get rid of this? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: It's not a new question exactly. When I use the map method, it gives me the list of key: value pairs, but in the console, I get the key prop warning.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not clear at all what you're observing.  Please illustrate fully in a new question.

Comment: Doing that. Thanks for the assistance.